# (Laravel Mix - Copy Directory) - How can style files be compiled after copying from scss,less to css

Tags: css, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I have this script

```
mix.copyDirectory('public/themes/assets', 'public/assets');
```

And I want to compile all scss,less files in this folder to css after copying, and left their in the same folder, is it possible?